# googlecolab からgoogledriveの共有フォルダにファイル出力したい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-drive-sdk

google colaboratory から共有設定したgoogle driveのフォルダにファイルを出力するには
どうすればいいでしょうか？
共有フォルダのidは分かっておりますが、どのように出力先を指定するば可能か、
アドバイスいただきたくお願い致します。

pydrive認証（コードスニペット利用）

```
# Import PyDrive and associated libraries.
# This only needs to be done once in a notebook.
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
# This only needs to be done once in a notebook.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

指定した共有フォルダに格納したい

フォルダid = "1FhrOPpDmWtSu7UDaCtM703d2KE****"
アップロードしたいファイル  /content/sample.pptx

サンプルコードの修正にて実現可能なのか、
別のアプローチが必要でしょうか。

```
# Create & upload a text file.
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Sample file.pptx'})
uploaded.SetContentString('Sample upload file content')
uploaded.Upload()
```

Comment: こんな記事があって承認されているので参考になるのでは？ [How to copy files from colab or cloud storage to google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56578685/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。driveをマウントし　!cp "colab-path" -r "drive-path"　でできました。他人とファイルを共有した際にpathが変わらなければそのまま使えそうです。

Comment: 実行した手順とか注意事項などを自己回答にしてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kunif さんにアドバイス頂いた方法にて解決しましたので、手順記載致します。

・google colaboratoryからgoogle driveの指定したフォルダにファイル転送する方法
・google driveからgoogle colaboratoryにファイル転送する方法

①　google driveをマウントします。

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
%cd /gdrive
```

②コマンド実行
送付元ファイルパス　 "/content/sample.pptx"
送付先ドライブパス　 "/gdrive/Shared drives/test/"
※googledrive上で予め共有フォルダtestを作成済
　左側サイドメニューにあるファイルより対象フォルダを右クリックしパスをコピー

```
!cp "/content/sample.pptx" -r "/gdrive/Shared drives/test/"
```